# Windows Identity Foundation - Programmatically Sign In on RP for SSO

Tags: visual-studio-2010, single-sign-on, wif

I've been trying to figure WIF out for a while now, and can force the user to sign in via my STS using passiveRedirectEnabled and restricting access to my site to known users.

I now want to rather use my own sign in view page on my RP and programmatically sign a user in across all of my sites trusting the same STS.

Users should be able to view my site completely, but have the option to sign in via a link in my site navigation.

I've looked for hours now and can't find a simple working answer to achieve this.

Is there something along the lines of `WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut` for sign in too?

How would I go about doing this, if it's at all possible.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is - have a look at [Establishing Trust from an ASP.NET Relying Party Application to an STS using the FederatedPassiveSignIn Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517286.aspx).

IIRC, this is part of the WIF SDK.

Comment: The problem with that method is that I'd still be sent to my STS to sign in. I'm looking for a solution whereas I can do all the logic on my Relying party and send the request to my STS which would then provide a session key.

Comment: By definition the STS is external to all your sites. There's no "session key". The STS will give you a "security token" which is (and should be) specific to a site.

Comment: Is there no way to send the user credentials to the STS, validating them at the STS and send a security token back to the RP, all without the user needing to physically visit the STS?

Comment: If you wanted to, you could create a WCF service talking to an active endpoint on the STS. You would pass the credentials to the web service, it returns a valid security token and you then use that to sort out your session and cookie. Would this approach work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to have users sign in once and be authenticated to multiple different relying party websites. So assuming you have an STS, with multiple trust relationships set up with RP1, RP2, RP3.

1. The user browses to RP1
2. RP1 redirects user to STS
3. User signs in at STS, which establishes a session, user now has STS session cookie

   - note this is the only step in which user interactive authentication is required, the rest is automated redirects
4. STS redirects back to RP1, and RP1 establishes a session, user now has RP1 session cookie as well

Having authenticated to your STS, your user has effectively authenticated to RP2, and RP3 as well. Here's what happens:

1. User browses to RP2
2. RP2 redirects to STS
3. STS sees the user already has an STS session cookie, so immediately issues a token for RP2, and redirects the user there
4. RP2 accepts the token from STS, and establishes a session, user now has RP2 session cookie

This is a very common mechanism, and it's a core scenario supported by WIF. For example after you've used your live ID to sign in to hotmail.com, you don't have to re-authenticate when you browse to manage.dev.live.com. This is because you have a liveID session cookie, from step 3 above.

Is this what you're looking for? If so, I can update with more detail.